# Any way to flip coordinates without reversing everything else?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a plotting function that has the option to flip coordinates (using `coord_flip`). The thing is, this is a plot by group (using the `fill` argument), which means, for some reason, `coord_flip` also reverses colors, legend, my value column and my fill column. In practice, this means I have the following pice of code in my function:

```
  if(flip_coord){
    colors = c("#CC0000", "#002D73" ) %>% rev
    rev_legend = T
    table[[col_plot]] = fct_rev(table[[col_plot]]) # value column
    table[['origin_table']] = fct_rev(table[['origin_table']]) # fill column
    
  } else{
    colors = c("#CC0000", "#002D73" ) 
    rev_legend = F
  }
```

There's also this line in my plot:

```
{if(flip_coord) coord_flip()} +
```

This brings back everything else that gets scrambled with `coord_flip`, but isn't too elegant. Is there a better way to only flip coordinates without reversing everything else?

PS: I know there's no reproducible example here, I'll try to add one, but if someone has already stumbled upon the answer to this problem that might be common, I'll post as is for the moment.

Edit: made some `reprex`. Let's say my data is this:

```
df =  tibble(origin = c('2000s', '1990s') %>% rep(2),
             region = c('South', 'North') %>% rep(2) %>% sort,
             value = 1:4) %>% 
  mutate(origin = factor(origin, levels = c('1990s', '2000s')),
         region = factor(region, levels = c('North', 'South')))

colors = c('red', 'blue')

# origin region value
# <fct>  <fct>  <int>
# 1 2000s  North      1
# 2 1990s  North      2
# 3 2000s  South      3
# 4 1990s  South      4
```

If I plot regularly, everything comes ordered (90s first, 00s second, North first, South second):

```
    df  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = region, fill = origin, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge', color = "white", alpha= 0.8)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors)
```

[image: a]

But, if I flip coordinates (just adding  `+ coord_flip()` to the code above) I get the following:

[image: b]

South above north, 00s above 90s and the legend isn't in the same order than the bars. This is exactly the same if I input `x = value` and `y = origin`. So, to fix this I have to do the following:

```
df2 = df
df2[['region']] = fct_rev(df2[['region']]) # Change 1
df2[['origin']] = fct_rev(df2[['origin']]) # Change 2

df2  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = origin, y = region)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge', color = "white", alpha= 0.8)  +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = T)) + # Change 3
  scale_fill_manual(values=rev(colors)) # Change 4
```

Bringing the correct orders:

[image: c]

Is there any less cumbersome way to achieve this?

Comment: As of `ggplot2` version 3.3.0 (March 2020), all geoms that use to only work in one direction are smart enough to work in both directions (e.g., box plots, violinplots, bars, etc.), which means that `coord_flip` is rarely needed. I'd suggest just switching your `x` and `y` aesthetics.

Comment: That said, this is very confusing. I've never known `coord_flip` to change the color scales or anything else. Here's a reproducible example showing that `coord_flip()` **doesn't** change a color scale: `p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = hp)) +geom_point()` , compare `print(p)` with `print(p + coord_flip())`, the color scale is unchanged. So if you want more help you really do need to add a reproducible example as you're describing non-standard behavior.

Comment: Added a reprex, took me a while!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `coord_flip()` changes the ordering of bars within groups in grouped bar plot:
According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49448497/coord-flip-changes-ordering-of-bars-within-groups-in-grouped-bar-plot) a hacky way to solve is to put width of position_dodge() to negative,

With `scale_x_discrete(limits=rev)+` we get North in correct position:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=region, y=value, fill=origin))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), width = -0.4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  coord_flip()+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=rev)+
  theme_minimal(base_size=16)+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I see! My only grip is that the _hacky ways_ are even less legible and my top priority is to produce legible code, so, sadly, I can't  use this option

Comment: Maybe option 2 of the mentioned site could be an option for you.

Answer (score 3):

Coord flip does *not* flip everything around. Factors are plotted starting from the bottom. Thus, 1990 will be below 2000, and North will be below South.

The simplest way I can see is to simply reverse your factor levels. (when creating your factors).

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  origin = c("2000s", "1990s") %>% rep(2),
  region = c("South", "North") %>% rep(2) %>% sort(),
  value = 1:4
) %>%
  mutate(
    ## just reverse the factor levels
    origin = factor(origin, levels = rev(c("1990s", "2000s"))),
    region = factor(region, levels = rev(c("North", "South")))
  )

colors <- c("red", "blue")

df %>%
  # switched x and y
  ggplot(aes(y = region, x = value, fill = origin)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "white", alpha = 0.8) +
## this is to set the correct legend order and mapping to your colors
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, breaks = rev(unique(df$origin)))
```

[image]